# Combine two AWK commands

Tags: parsing, awk

I have two command line with AWK which works perfectly independently:

```
awk 'FNR < 2' DATA   #parse out first line from DATA
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1; next} a[$1]'  LIST DATA #parse the matched elements between LIST and DATA
```

I need to parse first line for DATA as well as the matched elements between LIST and DATA in one output.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: An example would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your current codes:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1; next} FNR<2||a[$1]'  LIST DATA
```