# Combine two awk commands into one

Tags: awk

How can I combine the last two awk commands into one.

```
cut -d':' -f1,2,3,4,5 /etc/passwd |awk -F: '{print $5,$1}' |awk 'NF>=4'
```

I saw this question but I can't figure out how to apply it to this question.

[Combine two AWK commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367928/combine-two-awk-commands)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your command does.

1. Take the first five field from `/etc/passwd` separated by `:`
2. Then use  field `5` and field  `1` separated by `:`
3. Test to see if that is more or equal to  `4` fields separated by space.

Here is how I would do that:

```
awk -F: '{$0=$5" "$1} split($0,a," ")>3' /etc/passwd
```

`-F:` set field separator to `:`
`$0=$5" "$1` recreate line using field `5` and `1`
`split($0,a," ")` split the line using space, output of split is number of fields.
`split($0,a," ")>3` test if there are more than `3` fields. (We could also use `>=4`

Comment: +1. Functionally it won't matter in this case but it does in others (e.g. when an RE metacharacter is present and needs to be escaped) so it's good to get into the habit of using regexp delimiters for regexps (or field separators as in this case): `split($0,a,/ /)`. IMHO it makes the code clearer too.

Comment: Thanks @Jotne you also eliminated the cut and your explanation is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
cut -d':' -f1,2,3,4,5 /etc/passwd|awk -F: '
   {split($5, a, " "); split($1, b, " ");} 
   length(a) + length(b) >= 4 { print $5, $1}'
```

Or according to @shellter just:

```
awk -F: '{split($5, a, " "); split($1, b, " ");}
         length(a) + length(b) >= 4 { print $5, $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Since split returns number of splitted terms, we can simplify even further:

```
awk -F: 'split($5" "$1, a, " ") >=4 {print $5, $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: you don't even need the `cut` command, right? Too bad the OP didn't include sample data.

Comment: @shelter the sample is /etc/passwd I figured anyone answering this had access to a Linux /etc/passwd file